# I'm getting error in upgrading the gradle version from 6.8 to 7.4

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, spring-cloud-contract

I tried building my project with gradle version 7.4, but I couldn't. It was working fine with the gradle version 6.8.
I'm using the spring-cloud-contract-verifier version : 3.1.1

I got this kind of error message when I tried building with the gradle 7.4:

- What went wrong:
  Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':copyContracts' (type'ContractsCopyTask').

  - In plugin 'org.springframework.cloud.contract' type 'org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.plugin.ContractsCopyTask' property 'config.backupContractsFolder' of mutable type 'org.gradle.api.file.DirectoryProperty' is writable.

    Reason: Properties of type 'org.gradle.api.file.DirectoryProperty' are already mutable.

    Possible solution: Remove the 'setBackupContractsFolder' method.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/validation_problems.html#mutable_type_with_setter for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'org.springframework.cloud.contract' type 'org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.plugin.ContractsCopyTask' property 'config.contractsDirectoryPath' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Add an input or output annotation.
    2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'org.springframework.cloud.contract' type 'org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.plugin.ContractsCopyTask' property 'config.contractsMode' of mutable type 'org.gradle.api.provider.Property' is writable.

    Reason: Properties of type 'org.gradle.api.provider.Property' are already mutable.

    Possible solution: Remove the 'setContractsMode' method.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/validation_problems.html#mutable_type_with_setter for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'org.springframework.cloud.contract' type 'org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.plugin.ContractsCopyTask' property 'config.contractsPath' of mutable type 'org.gradle.api.provider.Property' is writable.

    Reason: Properties of type 'org.gradle.api.provider.Property' are already mutable.

    Possible solution: Remove the 'setContractsPath' method.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/validation_problems.html#mutable_type_with_setter for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'org.springframework.cloud.contract' type 'org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.plugin.ContractsCopyTask' property 'config.copiedContractsFolder' of mutable type 'org.gradle.api.file.DirectoryProperty' is writable.

    Reason: Properties of type 'org.gradle.api.file.DirectoryProperty' are already mutable.

    Possible solution: Remove the 'setCopiedContractsFolder' method.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/validation_problems.html#mutable_type_with_setter for more details about this problem.

Comment: What version of `spring-cloud-contracts` are you using? it was known issue in  `3.0.3`. Please check
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/1683 for details

Comment: This issue got resolved after using spring-cloud-contract version 3.1.1